# Why did Batman and Lt. Gordon let this character go?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-batman-2022

In *The Batman*, there is a shoot out and a car chase involving Batman, Lt. Gordon and The Penguin. Ultimately The Penguin gets caught, but it turns out he isn't the guy they're after so they seemingly let him go (he has his hands tied but is able to move. He is free again in a later scene).

Considering he was involved in a shoot out and a car chase incurring several wrecks that would have injured many innocents if not killed them, why did they just walk away and let him go? Even if the police force are corrupt, why make no attempt to even arrest him?

Comment: Narrative pacing would be my guess.

Answer (score 4):

I am assuming it's simply because they are after the bigger fish. They know Penguin's hideout, and they also know that Penguin is not the actual boss (at least wasn't then).